# Problem with elements that overlaped each other and hover

Tags: jquery

I have [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed5yw/13/). Element with class "help" and id "help" overlap each other. I want with hover on ".help" the "#help" show. But when click on ".onHelp" the "#help" couldnt close.
What is solution for such elements?

Thanks in advance

(I have edited jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #help div is under .help, while it should be in front, covering the "hover me" text. Adding positive `z-index` value to #help.

Comment: Clicking the .onHelp hide the #help, but then your mouse hovers over .help... witch shows #help again. You need to position onHelp or #help some place else. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nVNQZ/

Comment: I know that changing the position solve the problem but we cant change the orignal design

Comment: I see. Replace hover with mouseenter. It shouldn't show the popup until mouse pointer leaves "hover me" and comes back. Be sure to double check it in every browser as it might be tricky. If that won't work in every browser you'll have to do something nasty like: http://jsfiddle.net/vQvmH/

Answer (score 1):

Your .onHelp is overlapped by the .help that's why click event didn't get trigged. Either add z-index or change the postion of .onHelp div.See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed5yw/15/)

Comment: I cant chaneg the onHelp position, In original design, onHelp in over the #help with background image

Answer (score 0):

i think it's working [fine here...](http://jsfiddle.net/S6M6q/)

change motorola1.3.2 to jquery1.4 or whatever...in jsfidle :)

Comment: thanks vivek, but I cant change the css, two elements are overlap each other with background images